# Using window.onerror to catch throwing a string instead of an error object

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling

I have a general error handler, that is unable to catch all errors because some errors are thrown as a string.

For example

```
window.onerror = new function(msg, url, line, col, error){
    console.log(msg);
    //console.log(arguments);
};
```

Now if I throw this Exception:

```
throw new Error("Catch this")
```

The on error handler will log "Catch this";

The problem is if the exception is thrown in this manner:

```
throw "Catch this";
```

This will log "Script error."

I logged the arguments to look for the original error text thrown but it cannot be found anywhere. Is there a way to capture the message with the window.onerror?

The JQuery UI version I'm using sometimes throws errors as strings and cannot be captured.